# how to not show initialState in my ui redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

```js
import { PayloadAction, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

type TodolistState = {
  id: number,
  title: string,
  body: string,
  done: boolean
}[]

const initialState: TodolistState = [{
  id: Date.now(),
  title: 'test title',
  body: 'test body',
  done: false
}]

const todoSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'Todo',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    add: (state, action: PayloadAction<{ id: number, title: string, body: string, done: boolean }>) => {
      state.push(action.payload)
    },
    remove: (state, action: PayloadAction<{ id: number, done: boolean }>) => {
      state.splice(action.payload.id, 1)
    } 
  }
})
```

This is my how I display my UI.

[image]

```
function Display() {
  const data = useSelector((state:RootState) => state.todo)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  return (
    <>
      <Box sx={{ p: 2 }}>
        {data.map((val, index) => (
          <Paper
            elevation={3}
            sx={{
              p: 2,
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: 'column',
              gap: "10px",
              margin: "10px"
            }}
            key={index}
          >
            <div className="title">
              <Typography variant="h5">{val.title}</Typography>
            </div>
            <div className="body">
              <Typography variant="body1">{val.body}</Typography>
            </div>
            <div className="sf">
              <form action="" className="formbtn">
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  color="primary"
                  onClick={() => {
                    dispatch(remove({ id: index, done: true }))
                  }}
                >
                  Done
                </Button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </Paper>
        ))}
      </Box>
    </>
  )
}

export default Display
```

When I do show it like this `initialState` will show in my UI. How can I remove it?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the initial state to be rendered to the UI then simply don't provide it.

Instead of the "test" initial state:

```js
const initialState: TodolistState = [{
  id: Date.now(),
  title: 'test title',
  body: 'test body',
  done: false
}];
```

Simply provide an empty array:

```js
const initialState: TodolistState = [];
```

`Array.prototype.map` can handle empty arrays without issue.

In other words, `data.map(.....)` of the empty array `initialState` value will simply be an empty array and valid JSX.

Answer (score -2):

In Redux Toolkit, initialState is typically used when creating a slice using the createSlice function. If you don't want to expose the initialState in your UI, you can achieve this by not directly referencing it in your components.

Slice Creation:
When creating a slice, avoid exporting the initialState. Instead, export only the slice reducer and any action creators.

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  // Your initial state here
};

const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'mySlice',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    // Your reducers here
  },
});

export const { reducer: mySliceReducer } = slice;
export const { action1, action2 } = slice.actions;
```

Redux Store Configuration:
In your Redux store configuration, import and use the slice reducer directly.

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { mySliceReducer } from './path/to/mySlice';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    mySlice: mySliceReducer,
    // other reducers...
  },
});

export default store;
```

Connecting to Components:
When connecting your components to Redux, use useSelector to access the state managed by your slice, but don't directly reference initialState.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const data = useSelector((state) => state.mySlice.data);
  // Render your component based on the data
};

export default MyComponent;
```

By following this pattern, you can keep the initialState private within your slice implementation and only expose the necessary parts to your UI.